# gradle appengineRun failes with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, spring-boot, gradle

I want to rewrite this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard
simple spring boot app to use gradle instead of maven.

I mostly succeeded the **gradle bootRun** and **appengineDeploy** works fine but **appengineRun** FAILS with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find the main class to restart
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.doStart(Restarter.java:285)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.start(Restarter.java:273)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter$1.call(Restarter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter$1.call(Restarter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter$LeakSafeThread.run(Restarter.java:627)
error.
```

My gradle.build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()    // Bintray's repository - a fast Maven Central mirror & more
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:+")
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'
    }
}


repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'            // Google's mirror of Maven Central
    }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

enter code here

bootRepackage {
    enabled = false
}

configurations {
    compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-jetty"
}


dependencies {

    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:+'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
}



appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration
  run {      // local (dev_appserver) configuration (standard environments only)
    port = 8080                 // default
  }

  deploy {   // deploy configuration
    stopPreviousVersion = true  // default - stop the current version
    promote = true              // default - & make this the current version
  }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

The working pom.xml is at the git repo I linked above (stackoverflow doesnt allow me to use 2 links :-) )

I think the solution is easy I just dont have experience nor with gradle or appengine. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

removing the 
`compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")` dependency from the **gradle.build** file solves the problem. It would be good though if someone could explain why.